# Reference initialization in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

Consider the following snippet from the C++ standard 12.6.2/11:

```
struct A {
    A() = default; // OK
    A(int v) : v(v) { } // OK
    const int& v = 42; // OK
};
A a1; // error: ill-formed binding of temporary to reference
A a2(1); // OK, unfortunately
```

Why do they say that `A a2(1);` is bad? What is wrong?

Comment: It's bad because you're binding a reference to a temporary.

Comment: I don't think the first one should be an error but rather a warning. It compiles for me.

Comment: @0x499602D2 All right, what's wrong with binding a refernce to a temporary?

Comment: This temporary will expire at the end of the constructor leaving `v` a [*dangling reference*](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/340594/can-you-explain-dangling-references).

Comment: Is that in the C++14 standard?

Comment: @0x499602D2 are you using VS?

Comment: @0x499602D2 clang does issue a diagnostic message here, which is correct, as the program is invalid. Whether the message is an error or a warning is irrelevant as far as the standard is concerned.